# Wince 6.0 building issue

Tags: windows-ce

I have installed visual studio 2005 and then Wince 6.0 as evaluation on it.

I am a beginner to platform builder. When I build MyOsDesign Wince 6.0 platform builder, I see three errors in output:

1. Error: Could not find file
   'C:\WINCE600\MyOSDesigns\MyOSDesign1\MyOSDesign1\RelDir\WinCe6_0Training_ARMV4I_Release\kitl.dll'
   on disk
2. makeimg: FATAL ERROR: Command returned non-zero exit code 1 (dec).
3. makeimg: FATAL ERROR: Command returned non-zero exit code 1 (dec).

Can any one help in finding bug

Answer (score 1):

It looks like KITL didn't get built.  Without seeing the entire build log, we can only guess what happened. Even with the build log there's no guarantee we would know why it wasn't built - something in the BSP might be suppressing it as well.  Three things I'd try:

- Manually build just the KITL piece from the command line and makeimg again
- Try removing KITL from the OS (under project properties IIRC) completely and see if you can at least create an image without it
- Contact the OEM and make sure the BSP you got from them supports KITL (oddly enough, some don't)